# Check available email during registration (asp.net identity)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I would like to know how to check on whether the email is available in database either asynchronously when typing or the email text field is lost focus during registration process in ASP.NET Identity 2.0

Answer (score -1):

There is no possibility to make such check using ASP identity api, you have to make direct check on database, here is example using entity framework.

```
protected bool EmailAlreadyExists(string aEmail)
{          
    using( Baza pB = new Baza() )
    {
        if( pB.Memberships.Where( z => z.Email == aEmail).Count() > 0 )
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```